# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual...Line 6

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following a tutorial and I keep getting an error even though everything should seem right. This is in respect of MySQL query shown below:

```
$query = 'SELECT
              movie_namemovie_year,movie_director,movie_leadactor,movie_type,
              movie_running_time,movie_cost,movie_takings
          FROM 
              movie 
          WHERE 
              movie_id = ' . $__GET['movie_id'];
```

But I'm getting the error below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

The error,I think, refers to the last line of the above query. Yet, I can't figure out what is wrong with the query. Also just above this query is just a couple of functions and connection the database so I'm not sure it comes from that part of the code.

I'm using WAMPServer 2.5 on Windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably $__GET['movie_id'] is empty.

Comment: Looks like `$__GET['movie_id'];` is blank.

Comment: ` $__GET` did you mean `$_GET`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty it's actually $_GET in my code probably a typo here. thanks

Comment: @АлександрЛазарев ,jens can u please elaborate on '$_GET['movie_id']' being empty? I will really appreciate. New to this. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have there undefined variable, just one underscore is in `$_GET`

```
$query = 'SELECT movie_namemovie_year,
                 movie_director,
                 movie_leadactor,
                 movie_type,
                 movie_running_time,
                 movie_cost,
                 movie_takings
          FROM   movie 
          WHERE  movie_id = ' . (int)$_GET['movie_id'];
```

Comment: made the changes above but I still get exactly the same error. Can u please tell me which is the undefined variable? are u referring to `movie_id`?

Comment: @user958119: `$__GET` was undefined (with two underscores). Maybe the key, `movie_id` is undefined too. What returns `echo $_GET['movie_id']` before query (nothing, else the SQL query has to work)? Do you have `movie_id=XXX` in your URL? The whole script should be wrapped by conditon `if (isset($_GET['movie_id'])) {$query ...}` to avoid undefined variable and sql error.

Comment: (int)$_GET['movie_id'] will add a 0 to query string if $_GET['movie_id'] is empty. Maybe the problem is in other query? Show please all the script.